# With setuptools, when does namespace packages __init__.py files disappears?

Tags: python, setuptools, namespace-package

The [setuptools documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#namespace-packages) is very explicit about adding code to `__init__.py` files from namespaces:

> You must NOT include any other code and data in a namespace package's `__init__.py`. Even though it may appear to work during development, or when projects are installed as .egg files, it will not work when the projects are installed using "system" packaging tools -- in such cases the `__init__.py` files will not be installed, let alone executed.

Yet, I do not understand what these "system" packaging tools are. What are they? How could I reproduce this situation where the `__init__.py` files are gone?

Comment: Good question. I *guess* "system" packaging tools may refer to **apt-get** or **brew** and alike which install the package system-wide, whereas unlike **pip** as local-wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Anzel's comment looked like a good answer, and I'd say [PEP-420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) confirms that. In its [Rationale section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#rationale), we read:

> Namespace packages are designed to support being split across multiple directories (and hence found via multiple `sys.path` entries). In this configuration, it doesn't matter if multiple portions all provide an `__init__.py` file, so long as each portion correctly initializes the namespace package. However, **Linux distribution vendors (amongst others) prefer to combine the separate portions and install them all into the same file system directory.** This creates a potential for conflict, as the portions are now attempting to provide the same file on the target system - something that is not allowed by many package managers. Allowing implicit namespace packages means that the requirement to provide an `__init__.py` file can be dropped completely, and affected portions can be installed into a common directory or split across multiple directories as distributions see fit.

So yes, we cannot add any more code to our `__init__.py` files because OS package managers (and others) would prefer to merge them into only one directory tree.